# Firebase + Angular + User Associated Items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

If you look at my code below I can add a project and associate it with the user, but when I want to pull up a users projects I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I've also tried using $child on the top but that's not working either. Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('writer')

  .factory('Users', ['firebaseURI', '$firebase', 'Auth', function(firebaseURI, $firebase, Auth){

    var currentUser = Auth.currentUser,
        users = new Firebase(firebaseURI + 'users');

    function _getProjectsForCurrentUser(){
      return users.child(currentUser.id + '/projects/');
    }

    function _addProjectForCurrentUser(projectRef){
      users.child(currentUser.id + '/projects/' + projectRef.key()).set(true);
    }

    return {
      getProjectsForCurrentUser: _getProjectsForCurrentUser,
      addProjectForCurrentUser: _addProjectForCurrentUser
    };

  }])

  .factory('Projects', ['firebaseURI', '$firebase', 'Auth', 'Users', function(firebaseURI, $firebase, Auth, Users){

    var projectsRef = new Firebase(firebaseURI + 'projects'),
        projects = $firebase(projectsRef);


    function _getProjects(){
      return projects;
    }

    function _create(project){
      console.log('create', project);
      projects.$push(project).then(function(ref){
        Users.addProjectForCurrentUser(ref);
      }, function(error){
        console.log('Projects Error:', error);
      });
    }

    return {
      getProjects: _getProjects,
      create: _create
    };

  }])
;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your return block in the `Users` factory should be:

```
return {
  getProjectsForCurrentUser: _getProjectsForCurrentUser,
  addProjectForCurrentUser: _addProjectForCurrentUser
};
```

Note the extra `_`

Comment: I've +1 Vote up your answer

Comment: Sorry I actually have that correct in my code and the error is actually "undefined is not a function." Sorry about that.